# Showing notification to user at specific time, but it appears every time when i closed or open my application?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-notifications

The full scenario is I am trying to show notification according to user selected time for that I am using a `TimePickerDialog`, `BroadcastReceiver` class and a `Service` class, every thing is working fine notification also appears at specific times, but the problem is when I open and close the application every time notification comes.

> Activity.java

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ReminderActivity.this, MyBreakfastReciver.class);
System.out.println("getting Breakfast Reminder");
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ReminderActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

//bTimePart1 and bTimePart2 is the time choosen by user through time picker
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, bTimePart1 );
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, bTimePart2);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

> BroadcastReciever

```
public class MyBreakfastReciver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, MyBreakfastAlarmService.class);
        context.startService(service1);

    }

}
```

> Reciever class

```
 private void showNotification(Context context) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notificationlogo)
        .setContentTitle("DietGuru")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentText("You haven't logged your BreakFast for today.")
        .setSubText("Would you like to do it now?");


        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, CalorieMainActivity.class);

        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
        // started Activity.
        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
        // your application to the Home screen.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(CalorieMainActivity.class);

        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);


        resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                        );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        //mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.

        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

I just want to stop my notification when I open and close my application.

Comment: Among other possible problems, `calendar` may be in the past. If you use `set()` to adjust `Calendar` fields, always check to see if the result is in the past and adjust accordingly (e.g., `add()` a day).

Comment: If your time time selection is before ur current time then Alaram fire event so try to check if time is before current time then add day so Alaram fire event on next day with given time.

Answer (score 1):

If your time time selection is before ur current time then Alaram fire event so try to check if time is before current time then add day so Alaram fire event on next day with given time, Check below example with fire notifiaction 8 a.m on each day :

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
 // Set the alarm's trigger to next day if set alAram after 8 a.m.
 if(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)>8){
       calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
 }
 // Set the alarm's trigger time to 8:00 a.m.
 calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
 calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
 calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
```

Comment: Good effort bro but i added the same code still it's coming on closing and opening of the app